# Flutter webview with advanced scroll event

Tags: android, flutter, dart, webview

I have to implement flutter webview in the following manner:

```
ListView
    Widget
    Widget
    Webview
    Widget
```

The webview is auto scalling up to the height of the device (the content can be longer) and scrollable.
I have used this answer to make it scroll properly:
[Scrolling priority when combining horizontal scrolling with WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57069716/scrolling-priority-when-combining-horizontal-scrolling-with-webview/57150906#57150906)

The thing is, I want it to switch to the main ListView scroll once it's reaches the bottom or top of the Webview content. It should look like a widget implemented natively on the widget tree.

The easy solution would have been to make the Webview as high as the content, but the devices crashes above a certain Webview height (3000).

Would be happy to hear any solution.

Thanks.

Comment: no one have an answer?

Comment: have you achieved this?

Comment: Any news on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Since the screen has multiple scrollable widgets, you need to use `NestedScrollView`. Wrap the ListView with this widget.

```dart
var _scrollController = ScrollController();

...

NestedScrollView(
  controller: _scrollController,
  headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
    return ListView(
      // Add widgets and WebView here
    );
  }
)
```