# How to set the vertical scrolling angle setting

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to find out if there is an adjustment for the amount of angle tolerance for scrolling in Flutter.
Users like to navigate one handed using a thumb.
However, when doing this, the vertical thumb movement is not always completely vertical.
This causes the horizontal scroll to activate instead.
Is there a way to set the tolerance or the angle point in which this scroll behaviour switches from vertical to horizontal?

Answer (score 0):

It is handled internally for `GestureDetector`, in [docs for recognizing Gestures](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/advanced/gestures#gesture-disambiguation) it is mentioned that:

> For example, when disambiguating horizontal and vertical dragging, both recognizers enter the arena when they receive the pointer down event. The recognizers observe the pointer move events. If the user moves the pointer more than a certain number of logical pixels horizontally, the horizontal recognizer declares victory and the gesture is interpreted as a horizontal drag. Similarly, if the user moves more than a certain number of logical pixels vertically, the vertical recognizer declares victory.

on the same documentation page, [Pointers](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/advanced/gestures#pointers) are mentioned. It might be possible to do the computation for recognizing gestures ourselves but that might have performance impact.

Comment: Thanks. I will add an option to prevent the tabs from being selected with swipe action. Therefore the user can have it on or off to suit their own preference.

Comment: came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57069716/scrolling-priority-when-combining-horizontal-scrolling-with-webview) not sure if it would be helpful.@AlastairP

Comment: Thanks, I had a quick glance at it before heading out, and it looks promising. Will report back.