# Flutter: fixing syncfusion calendar scroll by forcing gesture arena winner?

Tags: flutter, syncfusion, gesture-recognition, syncfusion-calendar

I have a problem with [SyncFusion's flutter calendar](https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_calendar) which is demonstrated by this screenshot of `SfCalendar` showing months which is inside a `Column` with other children (also see end for minimal reporoducible example code):

[image]

The problem is simple: vertical scrolling works fine when the touch point begins on the other `Column` children, but when the touch point begins on the `SfCalendar` the `Column` does not scroll. The calendar seems to absorb all vertical drag touch gestures completely. This is extremely annoying, because SfCalendar in month mode makes no use of vertical drag gestures, so it really should allow the Column to scroll.

Setting `debugPrintGestureArenaDiagnostics = true` reveals what is going on when you try to scroll vertically on the calendar:

```
I/flutter (15390): Gesture arena 24   ❙ ★ Opening new gesture arena.
I/flutter (15390): Gesture arena 24   ❙ Adding: TapGestureRecognizer#6f41b(debugOwner: GestureDetector, state: ready, button: 1)
I/flutter (15390): Gesture arena 24   ❙ Adding: TapGestureRecognizer#0240c(debugOwner: GestureDetector, state: ready, button: 1)
I/flutter (15390): Gesture arena 24   ❙ Adding: VerticalDragGestureRecognizer#736cf(debugOwner: GestureDetector, start behavior: start)
I/flutter (15390): Gesture arena 24   ❙ Adding: HorizontalDragGestureRecognizer#bde3d(debugOwner: GestureDetector, start behavior: start)
I/flutter (15390): Gesture arena 24   ❙ Adding: VerticalDragGestureRecognizer#5137d(start behavior: start)
I/flutter (15390): Gesture arena 24   ❙ Closing with 5 members.
I/flutter (15390): Gesture arena 24   ❙ Rejecting: TapGestureRecognizer#6f41b(debugOwner: GestureDetector, state: possible, button: 1, sent tap down)
I/flutter (15390): Gesture arena 24   ❙ Rejecting: TapGestureRecognizer#0240c(debugOwner: GestureDetector, state: possible, button: 1, sent tap down)
I/flutter (15390): Gesture arena 24   ❙ Accepting: VerticalDragGestureRecognizer#736cf(debugOwner: GestureDetector, start behavior: start)
I/flutter (15390): Gesture arena 24   ❙ Self-declared winner: VerticalDragGestureRecognizer#736cf(debugOwner: GestureDetector, start behavior: start)
```

There appear to be two `VerticalDragGestureRecognizer`s - I'm guessing that one is the `SingleChildScrollView` and the other is `SfCalendar` (again, I have no idea why the calendar has a vertical drag recogniser, because it has no vertical drag functionality). It looks like the Calendar wins the arena for a vertical drag, then just swallows the event and does nothing.

**So my question is:**

**How do I make my `SingleChildScrollView` win the arena? Or is there any other way to make this work?**

Minimal reproducible example:

**pubspec.yaml**

```
name: syncfusioncalendarscroll
description: A new Flutter application.

publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  syncfusion_flutter_calendar: ^18.1.59-beta

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
```

**main.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:syncfusion_flutter_calendar/calendar.dart';

void main() {
  debugPrintGestureArenaDiagnostics = true;
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(
              height: 700,
              child: Placeholder(color: Colors.amber),
            ),
            SfCalendar(
              view: CalendarView.month,
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 700,
              child: Placeholder(color: Colors.blue),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: will [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57069716/scrolling-priority-when-combining-horizontal-scrolling-with-webview) be of help?

Answer (score 0):

We have already found and fixed the reported issue “Scrolling not working when touchpoint is on the calendar inside a column”. We will include the issue fix in our upcoming Volume 2 release which is expected to roll out at the end of this week.

You can also contact us through our [support forum](https://www.syncfusion.com/forums), [Direct-Trac](https://www.syncfusion.com/support/directtrac/incidents), or [feedback portal](https://www.syncfusion.com/feedback/flutter). We are always happy to assist you!